# auto select datagrid row

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a datagrid. How can I put the focus on a particular row (ie row #5) of a datagrid via actionscript?

I'm partially there, but not quite:

stage.focus = myDG;

this obviously just sets the focus to the datagrid and not the row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myDG.selectedIndex = 5;
```

Also, if the row you want selected is not currently visible (and you need to scroll down), just call `scrollToIndex(5)`